# How can i dont close program automatically in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

codeblocks close console window automatically. i may use

```
system("pause")
```

But it is not comfortable, i would like make it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution to your problem in this setting:

> Project -> Properties -> Build Targets -> [Debug/Release/Any other Build Target you definend] -> Pause when execution ends

Answer (score -2):

Little hard to understand your issue, try adding it near the bottom with semi colon:

```
system("pause");
```

like so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "enter first name";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Hello, " << s << '\n';
    system("pause"); // <------------
    return 0; // optional
}
```

Comment: i wouldnt like add system("pause") in all my program, in previous version codeblocks it were automatically

Comment: Try cin.get(); to pause execution but note, you might have to call cin.sync() first.